# HTTP to HTTP Apache2 Rewrite not being used

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, redirect

I want all traffic sent on HTTP redirected to port 443.

I curently have a Rewrite rule set up for port 80 in the sites-available apache2 directory but when I go to that address on that port it still takes me to the default Ubuntu apache page instead of redirecting to the HTTPS site.

[image]

I have only 1 conf file in sites-available and the section in question looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:80>
    ServerAdmin some@email.com.au
    ServerName some.dns.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

I've restarted apache and checked there are no errors. Is there somewhere else I need to update?

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html - Don’t use mod-rewrite for a simple redirect to https. -_-_ In addition you need to set up a second VirtualHost block on port 443 for the https version of your site.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks I'll try a simple redirect. I already have a 443 host I just didn't provide that in the example.

Comment: The issue was actually 2 HTTPS rules on the same IP Address which is not allowed.